# What's the best way of checking if an object property in php is undefined?

Tags: php, object, undefined

What's the best way of checking if an object property in php is undefined?

Comment: `is_null()` or `=== null`.

Comment: Best way is opinion based

Comment: No @Andreas its code for "dont have a clue"

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know. But that "code" means there is a close reason. Asking the same question correct is better. Although in this case it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is_null`
Or
`!isset($object)`

Example :

I want to check if the input is undefined. So, I can show errors.

```
if (!isset($_POST['myInput'])) { echo "error"; } else { // do the code }
```